# PHP's mail() function messes up HTML in email message

Tags: php, email

So I have the following code. It's supposed to send HTML emails that were edited in the precedent screen. However, once the email is sent, in html tags, the first double quote and letter of each tag go missing, for instance,

```
<span style="something">
```

becomes

```
<span style=omething">
```

The odd part is, the message is printed fine if echoed to the screen, so I don't think it has anything to do with how it's being sent to the whole function, but how it's being sent to the mail() function...but I have no clue what the issue could be. Here is the code, without all the getting of variables and such because i don't think it's particularly relevant.

```
//start of the headers
$headers = "From: $from_name<$from_email>\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <$reply_to>\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/related; type=\"multipart/alternative\"; boundary=\"----=MIME_BOUNDRY_main_message\"\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Sender: $from_name<$from_email>\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP4\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n"; //1 = Urgent, 3 = Normal
$headers .= "Return-Path: <$from_email>\n"; 
$headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";
$headers .= "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_main_message \n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"----=MIME_BOUNDRY_message_parts\"\n"; 

$message = "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_message_parts\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";  //changed to support html
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n"; 
$message .= "\n"; 
/* note: add HTML by changing the Content-Type to text/html */
////TEST 1 - this is where i attempted to hardcode some code in to see if it would send properly: it wouldn't. printed fine though.
$message .="<font class=\"Apple-style-span\" face=\"'Courier New'\" size=\"5\">\n"; 
$message .= "bbbbb<b>bbbb<i>bbb<u>bbb<font class=\"Apple-style-span\" color=\"#000099\">\n"; 
$message .= "bbbbb<span class=\"Apple-style-span\" style=\"background-color: rgb(102, 255, 204);\">bbbbbb</span></font></u></i></b></font>\n";
/////end test 1
$message .= $body.'\n';
$message .= "\n\n"; 
$message .= "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_message_parts--\n"; 
if($file_present==1){ // added this to fix empty file bug
$message .= "\n"; 
$message .= "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_main_message\n"; 
$message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n\tname=\"" . $attachment_name . "\"\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n\tfilename=\"" . $attachment_name . "\"\n\n";
$message .= $data; //The base64 encoded message 
$message .= "\n"; 
$message .= "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_main_message--\n"; 
}
echo $message; //this is where it echoes fine, with all tags intact
// send the message
   if( mail("$to_name<$to_email>", $subject, $message, $headers)){ //this is where it goes wrong.
     echo("<p>Message successfully sent to ".$to_email.".</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery to ".$to_email." failed.</p>");
  }
```

Comment: First off, separate your HTML and PHP. Either use a template or output buffering. Make sure you avoid the `\"`

Comment: I suggest using PHPMailer - http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examples

Comment: either use a template or a template

Comment: for what it is worth, I think your error is elsewhere, despite what you say about "//this is where it echoes fine, with all tags intact
". mail() shouldn't touch your message.

Comment: In the line `$message .= $body.'\n';`, use double quotes instead of single.  The `\n` won't expand properly unless double-quoted.

Comment: Also, don't use \n , you're in html, use <br> (in message body of course)

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions, i'll try them all out tomorrow. one of them is bound to work. taking a break for today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've been going through my old questions. Figured I should post how I solved this. My initial assumption for this was right: there was nothing wrong with the body of the message. The issue was...

The headers! No, it doesn't really make sense to me. But after I initially removed the X-Sender/related header information, everything started sending almost fine. Then I changed the boundary to a random value, and suddenly everything worked fine. Anyone who can explain to me why this happens is welcome to, but I'm just glad it works.

Answer (score 1):

When outputting HTML using PHP, I find it easier to do things like this:

```
$content = '<span class="something">' . $someDynamicVariable . '</span>';
```

This avoids the nightmare that is escaping double quotes.

Comment: that's actually why I put the $message .= $body in single quotes, to see if it would fix it. i think i am going to try out the phpmailer someone posted, to see if it really is the mail() or not

Comment: where I see that in your example $message .= $body.'\n'; You'll be outputting a literal "backslash n" and not a carriage return. Only double quotes will interpret that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$headers .= "...[snip]... boundary=\"----=MIME_BOUNDRY_message_parts\"\n"; 
                                    ^--here                          ^--here
```

You're embedding quotes into the boundary string, but not using the quotes for the actual boundaries.

The boundary portion on of the content-type header should not have quotes in it.

For multi-line string generation, particularly with embedded quotes (e.g. HTML), I **STRONGLY** suggest you use a HEREDOC:

```
$message .= <<<EOL
<font class="Apple-style-span" face="'Courier New'" size="5">
bbbbb<b>bbbb<i>bbb<u>bbb<font class="Apple-style-span" color="#000099">
bbbbb<span class="Apple-style-span" style="background-color: rgb(102, 255, 204);">bbbbbb</span></font></u></i></b></font>
EOL;
```

is far more legible than the repeated concatenation method, and doesn't need ANY escapes on the quotes. As a bonus, you can even embed variables into the string as you would with any other normal double-quoted string in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you have an unescaped quote, possibly entering via a PHP variable into the HTML.  You need to call `htmlentities($variable, ENT_QUOTES)` on all of the variables that will end up inside the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that mail() treats double quotation mark as a special symbol and because you are sending all of the string inside quotations, then mail() may not be able to tell where your string ends and where it continues again.

I suggest replacing all of the double quotations inside your string with a single quotation as the HTML will allow that due to its flexibility.

so try this

```
<span style='Something'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted printable([see here](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/8169-mail-sent-php-outlook-missing-two-characters-after-every-equals-sign)).